# ¿Cómo crear tablas permanentes en Flink SQL?

Tags: datatable, hive

En la documentación de Flink SQL se hace referencia a que pueden crearse tablas permanentes, pero en ningún momento explica como.

La única referencia que hay a lo largo de la documentación es la siguiente:

*Las tablas permanentes requieren un catálogo (como Hive Metastore) para mantener los metadatos sobre la tabla. Una vez que se crea una tabla permanente, es visible para cualquier sesión de Flink que esté conectada al catálogo y seguirá existiendo hasta que la tabla se elimine explícitamente*

Si alguien sabe cuales son los pasos a seguir o conoce alguna documentación detallada, me vendría bien.

Gracias

Comment: ¿ Conseguiste resolverlo ?